# DeviceCheck token from NSData (Objective C)

Tags: objective-c

Using the new DeviceCheck API - I am generating a token using:

```
[DCDevice.currentDevice generateTokenWithCompletionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable token, NSError * _Nullable error)
```

I'm successfully authenticating with a signed JWT to:

```
https://api.development.devicecheck.apple.com/v1/validate_device_token
```

But the response is:

```
Missing or incorrectly formatted device token payload
```

This is a sample of the payload:

```
{"device_token":"0200000072912.......<rest of tokenString>","transaction_id":"ac61b285-4420-4b7e-a750-fef2b9f3419c","timestamp":1506150851000}
```

So, my question is - how do I get the token from NSData - none of these approaches work:

```
NSString *tokenString = [[token description] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
          tokenString = [tokenString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];


NSString *tokenString = [token base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];


const unsigned *tokenBytes = [token bytes];
NSString *tokenString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%08x%08x%08x%08x%08x%08x%08x%08x",
                        ntohl(tokenBytes[0]), ntohl(tokenBytes[1]), ntohl(tokenBytes[2]),
                        ntohl(tokenBytes[3]), ntohl(tokenBytes[4]), ntohl(tokenBytes[5]),
                        ntohl(tokenBytes[6]), ntohl(tokenBytes[7])];



NSMutableString *hexToken;
const unsigned char *iterator = (const unsigned char *) [token bytes];
hexToken = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < token.length; i++)
{
   [hexToken appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02lx", (unsigned long) iterator[i]]];
}
NSString *tokenString = [NSString stringWithString:hexToken];
```

The Apple Developer Forum is not helpful - the only other question I've found suggests that the token expires within a minute - I'm posting to the server within a few seconds.

I'm using Java HttpPost - and adding the payload using:

```
StringEntity params = new StringEntity(jsonPayload);

httpPost.setEntity(params);
```

If I modify the timestamp to seconds rather than milliseconds I get an error about the timestamp, so I'm assuming I'm getting the payload to the servers correctly.

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so option #2 was the right answer:

```
NSString *tokenString = [token base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
```

The server response can be misleading - note that the same response:

```
Missing or incorrectly formatted device token payload
```

Can be returned if you try to post a JSON payload with the same transaction_id more than once, or sending the same device_token (if a 200 has already been returned) more than once.